# Python MySQLdb WHERE SQL LIKE

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have recently started to learn Python and MySQL for web purposes and I have run into a following problem :

I want to pull out from a mysql database one record that contains any text that I enter in param section, howerver I am running into following problem when making a query:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Strielok/Desktop/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE params LIKE ('%s%') LIMIT 1"  % (param))
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb



db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                          user = "root",
                          passwd = "root",
                          db = "test")
param = "Test"

par = param

c = db.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE params LIKE ('%s%') LIMIT 1"  % (param))


data = c.fetchall()
print data

c.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Directly inserting the data into the SQL string is not the best way to do this, as it is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should change it to this:

`c.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE params LIKE %s LIMIT 1", ("%" + param + "%",))`

Comment: Oops, you're totally correct @univerio. Deleted my answer, yours is better.

Comment: thanks, your solution was the best, I like this section " ("%" + param + "%",)"

Answer (score 2):

A better aproach (and safer), instead to use a string as `"%" + param + "%"` would be to escape `%` char in template string with another `%` (so, `%%`), so it'll be:

`c.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE params LIKE '%%%s%%' LIMIT 1", (param,))`

Answer (score 0):

Your not using a proper parameter. Python is expecting another qualifier in this area `('%s%___')` in order to do a string substitution. This is also vulnerable code. The proper way to do this would look more like:

`c.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE params LIKE  '%%s%'  LIMIT 1",(param,))`

Comment: I don't think this will result in the same query. The final string will a LIKE clause of %param%, rather than param%, as @univerio intends.