# How to use mysql FROM_UNIXTIME in python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to execute this sql:

```
sql = "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%H') FROM aaa"
```

But it generates the following error message:

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

I've found some answers,which recommend me to change '%' by '%%',but I have to use this symbol in sql. How to solve this?

Comment: Probably this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903497/python-mysqldb-where-sql-like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python MySQLdb WHERE SQL LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903497/python-mysqldb-where-sql-like)

Comment: @Raf how is this duplicated to the question you link? It is also a SELECT sql query in Python, that part is true. But the problem he is facing here is related with FROM_UNIXTIME() which is not mentioned at all in the question you linked

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the format argument in

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%H')
```

> MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() returns a date /datetime from a version of
>   unix_timestamp. The return value is in ‘YYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS’ format
>   or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format depending upon the context of the
>   function ( whether numeric or string). If specified, the result is
>   formatted according to a given format string.

So that means '%H' is invalid. You should choose between:

- 'YYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
- YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu

Some Examples:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php