# Console.log shows "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)" when sending a POST request via AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, api, flask

I'm trying to create a simple search box using Flask, when I put "m" in the box, it should get a response from AJAX API showing only people names starting with "m" without the page refresh. I stored 5 names in SQL workbench starting with "m", but when I put "m" in the box, the Chrome inspect shows

> POST http://localhost:5000/users/find 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
>   jquery.min.js:2

The inspect Network->Response(Preview) both show

> NameError: name "username" is not defined.

The search box is defined in "index.html".

I tried to change the name to 'username', it did not work, and I don't not really understand those errors.

My api.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/users/find', methods=['POST'])
def find():
    mysql = connectToMySQL('usersApi')

    query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE %(starts_with)s"
    data = {
        starts_with: request.form['starts_with' + "%"]
    }
    users = mysql.query_db(query,data)
    print(data)
    return render_template('users.html',users=users)
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form id='myForm' method= 'POST' action='/users/find'>
      <input type="text" id="starts_with" name="starts_with"/>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#starts_with').keyup(function(){
        console.log("came here")
        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/users/find',
          data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
            console.log('received response:', response);
            $('#placeholder').html(response)
        }
        })
        })
      })

    </script>
```

My user.html:
    (this is the page where I want to show all the names start with "m", when I put "m" in the search box)

```
   <div id="all">
      {% for user in users %}
        <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
```

mySQL table name is "users" and column name is "name". I didn't put JSON yet, I hope to get it working via console.log first.

Could you please advise me on the resolution of the above errors?

Answer (score 0):

The following is invalid for getting the value from your form:

```
starts_with: request.form['starts_with' + "%"]
```

Should be:

```
starts_with: request.form['starts_with']
```

Also, I recommend having a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903497/python-mysqldb-where-sql-like) question (and answers) highlighting the security risks (sql injection) of building your query this way.